# File.StartUpload - uploads empty file

Tags: sharepoint, csom

Trying to test upload file using File.StartUpload but end up uploading empty file.

Every time a file is created with the expected file size, but no data is on the file. No exception or errors thrown, but file is empty.
[Code sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60csq.png)

Comment: Please copy/paste source code instead of sharing a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't comment on you to get information because I don't have enough points, but I still hope to help you.
I am very sorry here.
As John Wu said, you can provide detailed code, and we can debug and modify it through your code, which can better help you solve the problem.

From the code picture you provided, I think you can try to output the local file to see if you can get the file content.